# Mix s:Button and s:ToggleButton in s:ButtonBar

Tags: apache-flex

I would like some of the buttons in s:ButtonBar not to have a selected state.
Imagine a menu where some buttons instead of opening a pop-up perform an action (they don't have to be selected while the pop-up is open).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't actually ask a question, but I think I get what your after.

The buttons are created using factories defined as [skin parts](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/ButtonBar.html#top) in the ButtonBar.  In theory you could create your own custom classFactory to create a Button or ToggleButton based on some criteria.

It may be necessary to extend the ButtonBar to make it work, though.

Comment: I'm almost positive you do have to extend the ToggleButtonBar in this case because it internally stores that it will use the Button class to create it's instances and the ClassFactory isn't publicly exposed so far as I know.

Comment: @shaunhusain The button factories are skin parts, which are public properties on the component.  I see no reason you can't create your own factory to make some buttons a ToggleButton and some a regular Button.  You may be right about needing to extend the class, though. I'll modify my answer.

Comment: I think Adobe should add this feature to the framework: not all items in the s:MenuBar (doesn't exist) are toggle buttons. mx:MenuBar can display items that don't open a pop-up but those are still toggle buttons and have a selected state.

Comment: @hidarikani then be sure to put in a feature request at either http://ideas.adobe.com or http://bugs.adobe.com/flex/ .  I'm not sure exactly what you're asking for.

Comment: @flextras, I may have been thinking of the Flex 3 implementation, sorry I've only begun dabbling in 4 need to get used to making that distinction

Comment: @shaunhusain I'm actually surprised they aren't exposed as factories in the MX one.  But,  I can't find the property / style that does it, so probably not.